# OneToOneField to abstract model

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class

I'm looking to create a database structure where each Group has a link to a *single* Policy.

A Policy can be one of a variety of different types, each of which:-

- *may* have extra attributes
- will *definitely* have a method called do_this() and one called do_that()

Over time, more Policys will be created, each with their own attributes etc.

My initial instinct with this was to go with Policy being an abstract class with a link back to the Group and stubs for the methods:-

```
class Policy(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def do_this():
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def do_that():
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Then different policy types can add their own attributes but they have to implement the interface.

```
class PolicyA(Policy):
    new_attribute = models.IntegerField()

    def do_this():
        # implementation A

    def do_that():
        # implementation A
```

But if I do that, then I have no way of asking a Group for it's Policy, as Policy is abstract.

If I remove the abstract setting, then (using something like django model utils, I guess) I can get the "real" type of the Policy at runtime but that doesn't feel right to me.

I've read up a bit on generic relations but is that the "right" way to go here? I just want to be sure before I gallop off down one path or other.

Comment: To access the policy from a group you can add a related_name: ´group = models.OneToOneField(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='policy')´ so you can access it via ´some_group_object.policy ´ this will return ´<PolicyA: PolicyA object (1)>´ or PolicyB if it had a B

Answer (score 0):

I would make Policy a main model, and PolicyA a proxymodel.

```
from model_utils.managers import QueryManager
class Policy(models.Model):
    group = models.OneToOneField(Group)
    content_type = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=settings.CONTENT_TYPE,editable=False)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Policy, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.content_type = self.DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE

class PolicyA(Content):
    DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = settings.A_TYPE
    objects = QueryManager(content_type=DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do here.

Firstly, what is Content and why does PolicyA derive from it?

Secondly, if I (for example) call my_group.policy.do_this(), surely this will call the do_this() method of Policy, rather than that of PolicyA - even if the real class of the policy is PolicyA?

I'm not sure you've solved the issue here.